# What DLSR should I buy?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

I am pretty much a beginner in photography. But I want to buy new a camera and lenses, so I need your help.

Is it better to spend more money for the body or for lenses?.

Whic DSLR camera is good for beginners. I would like to take portraits and macro photos. I just love this ! But can't do with this old camera :).

Let me know what would you recommend.

Comment: And to answer if you should spend more on body or lenses - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18394/is-lenses-which-make-your-photographs-not-camera-bodies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also new in photography and had the same question as you. After days and days of reading, I decided to buy Nikon D5100. This is entry lever DSLR with good sensor and image quality, and really good price. This DSLR comes with standard kit Nikkor DX 18-55 which is good for begginers, and also for portrait shots. Yesterday I took on makro photo of flower and it looks like:

[image]

You should really read reviews of Canon and Nikon entry level DSLR-s to chose which one best fits to you. Good page to start is http://snapsort.com/compare, where you can compare cameras which you are interested in, and learn something about camera specifications.

Also, there are online guides, and books which explains how to buy new camera. These are links I followed:

http://digital-photography-school.com/how-to-buy-a-digital-camera
http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2012/12/14/how-to-buy-a-camera-5-things-you-need-to-know-about-choosing-a-dslr/

and of course http://www.photo.stackexchange.com :)

Hope, I helped!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. For now I was looking for these camera Canon 550 D what do you think is it worth buying. 

When I'll get better I'll go for something better like Canon 7D

Comment: Well your first step is to  see all specifications of Cannon 550D camera, see image examples and general pros and cons of camera. After that, see if there is another camera which fits your needs, and compare it with 550D. It is better to spent 5 days of analyseing every model which you are interested in, then buying the first one you see, and after regretting because it doesn't fit your needs.